# how to make image side by side with form in html php

Tags: php, html, css, forms, image

i want to make a form with image on its side as image below , and this is my form
Thank you

```
          <div class="col-5">
            <label for="nomor_servis">Nama Bengkel</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama_bengkel" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <label for="nomor_servis">Nama Bengkel</label>
            <textarea name="alamat" class="form-control" cols="10" rows="4" placeholder="Alamat"></textarea>
            </textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <label for="nomor_servis">Tanggal Berdiri</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama_bengkel" class="form-control">
          </div>
```

[image]

Comment: show the complete code that you have done right now

Comment: You can make two divs, side by side, one for the form, one for the image.

Comment: you already use template, you can find about grid system on the template site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using flexbox**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
        .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        }
    
        .flex-container > div {
        line-height: 75px;
        font-size: 30px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <label for="nomor_servis">Nama Bengkel</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama_bengkel" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <label for="nomor_servis">Nama Bengkel</label>
            <textarea name="alamat" class="form-control" cols="10" rows="4" placeholder="Alamat"></textarea>
            </textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <label for="nomor_servis">Tanggal Berdiri</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama_bengkel" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img style="width: 400px; height: 400px" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bootstrap Gird System for doing it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 10px;">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> 
      <img style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Imgur_logo.svg/1200px-Imgur_logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```